# CSS property shortcuts in Chrome devtools?

Tags: html, css, intellij-idea, google-chrome-devtools, keyboard-shortcuts

I was wondering if there are (or if not, customize..) keyboard shortcuts for css properties in devtools.

In intelliJ, i have fz + tab -> font-size, bgc + tab -> background-color, and so on.

It's pretty annoying to always have to type the whole background-c until i get "background-color" as a suggestion..

Is there a way to define shortcuts? or maybe a kind of smart search (enter bcol and it finds **b**ackground-**col**or)? something third-party?

i really like to try my css changes on a live site, but it takes so much time to enter them

Comment: See https://crbug.com/486015 - fuzzy search is planned. Recently it was added to js in Console and Sources.

Comment: Currently you can use an external utility that allows expansion of keyboard macros.

Comment: that's exactly what i want :) but it looks like it's not actively developed at all :/ can't be so hard to do, i imagine? i guess i'll have to use some kind of text expander until then... thanks!

Comment: I want precisely the same. Did you find a good workflow with an expander, or maybe something else? According to [this request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=897015): *"There's been multiple experiments for this, each didn't land because of some usability concerns."*